# Import responses from Adobe

Tags: cognito-forms

Can we export our responses from Adobe into Cognito along with the form itself?

Also, can we batch print?

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) supports bulk importing of form designs from Adobe FormsCentral, but does not support importing responses.  Adobe requested that we not ask for Adobe usernames and passwords due to security concerns (which I agree with) and the alternatives were too complicated for our users to make it worth implementing.  We have verified with Adobe that, because of our approach, our import tool will still work after the June 23rd deadline.

We do not currently have batch printing support.  We are actively working on PDF generation capabilities and will eventually support some form of batching, but will start with the ability to do things like include PDF's as email attachments for notifications.

Check out our Idea Board for more insight into what we are working on:
https://trello.com/b/ZS1698De/idea-board